# How to view Java-provided classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, javadoc, attachment

How can I see for example the content(raw Java code) of DefaultTableModel.class in Eclipse? It says Source not Found and I tried to set it to a downloaded javadocs folder but it is still not showing. How do I attach a source and where can I find one?

Comment: Just use a JDK instead of a JRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO `CTRL + SHIFT + T` in eclipse , It will now show a screen saying source not found.In the same  screen there is a link for "Attach source...". Click that link and import the src.zip file from your JDK installation directory. Thats it